# Strange linking behaviour with weak symbols (ARM-EABI unwinding routines __cxa_begin_cleanup)

Tags: gcc, linker, libstdc++, weak-linking

I've got a problem with our ARM-EABI toolchain and/or libstdc++.

When I compile and link a simple C++ library consisting of the files
test.cpp, TestClass.cpp, TestClass.h
some unwinding support routines like `__cxa_begin_cleanup` are weak-referenced from the library,
`objdump -T` showing them as

```
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000 __cxa_begin_cleanup
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000 __cxa_call_unexpected
```

`__cxa_begin_cleanup` is implemented in libsupc++, which our library is linked with, but the function is not linked into the library.
Why?

If the code from the library is changed and a `std::string` is used (prepared in comments in test.cpp), the function `__cxa_begin_cleanup` will be linked to the resulting binary and `objdump -T` won't show them anymore.

There is a similar issue [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00320.html), but the mentioned linker options `--start-group` and `--end-group` didn't help.

Can anyone help?

The ARM-EABI toolchain consists of:
GCC 6.3.0
Binutils 2.27
Newlib 2.4.0

Commandline:

```
arm-eabi-gcc.exe test.cpp TestClass.cpp -fPIC -O0 -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -o a.out
```

Source:

test.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "testclass.h"

int bur_heap_size = 0;

//std::string str1;

int fun ()
{
   TestClass obj1;
//   str1 = "blabla";
   return 0;
}
```

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "testclass.h"

TestClass::TestClass(){    public_member = 1;}
TestClass::~TestClass(){}
int TestClass::PublicMethodGetPublicMember(){    return public_member;}
```

TestClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H_
#define TESTCLASS_H_

class TestClass
{
    public:
    TestClass();
    ~TestClass();
    int PublicMethodGetPublicMember();
    public:
    int public_member;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ELF Standard](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) p. 1-18:

> When the link editor searches archive libraries, it extracts archive
>   members that contain definitions of undefined global symbols. The
>   member’s definition may be either a global or a weak symbol. **The link
>   editor does not extract archive members to resolve undefined weak
>   symbols.** Unresolved weak symbols have a zero value.

This means for the example above, no object will be extracted from the library, because of the weak-declaration. But the usage of std::string leads to the extraction of the object, which also satisfies the used weak-Symbols.

To "solve" this, it is possible to use the linker option `-u symbol`:

> Force symbol to be entered in the output file as an undefined symbol.
>   Doing this may, for example, trigger linking of additional modules
>   from standard libraries.